# Bottom Navigation Not showing original color

Tags: android, android-xml, android-bottomnav, android-bottomnavigationview

I have designed a bottom navigation view for my application. The idea is simple, green colored bottom bar will have white colored icons. I wrote a selector for this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@android:color/white" />
     <item android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"  />
  </selector>
```

And it works, it changes the icon colors, but it does not make it completely white, the color looks gray-ish.
I have also tried the `<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />` but it also doesn't work. I have added the images below for you to see the difference.

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 5):

If you want your icon to have same default color use this in your activiy.

```
bottomNavigation.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

**theme.xml**

```xml
<item name="elevationOverlayEnabled">false</item>
```

It appears that for anything that has `elevation` set, there will be an overlay. In my case my `BottomNavigationView` had `elevation` manually set and thus received a dark overlay.

Answer (score 0):

You should use state_selected

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_selected="true"
      android:color="@color/color1" />
   <item android:color="@color/color2" />
</selector>
```

> app:itemIconTint="@color/navigate_state"

Comment: check my complete question. I have mentioned that I tries this as well. No luck

Comment: i have already used selector. Where is the your  selector. i saw your question.

Comment: Selector have to be in color folder.

Comment: I know, it in colors folder only. If it was error in the selector, then it would not work at all. Currently it is showing dull color

Comment: So you check your BottomNavigationView. Do you use any styles?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"  />
</selector>
```

and kind of

```
add it on android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state" app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
```

Comment: I did.. it is not working. You can see that it is changing the color to white, but the white is not at all crisp. It looks like an overlay.

Answer (score 0):

If you using BottomNavigationView from com.google.android.material, you should specified colors especially for icon and text, for example:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_bar_icon_tint"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_bar_icon_tint"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />
```

and bottom_bar_icon_tint.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:color="@color/cool_grey"  />
</selector>
```

also pay attention to: android:state_checked="true"

Comment: I did.. it is not working. You can see that it is changing the color to white, but the white is not at all crisp. It looks like an overlay.

Comment: what happens if you change that white color to another color? try some own color from `colors.xml` not from android resources.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml files seems to have an alpha channel/transparency

You need to change the "android:alpha" parameter to "1.0" or remove it in your icon.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24"
android:tint="@color/white"
android:alpha="0.8">

<path
  android:fillColor="@color/white"
  android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM12,20c-4.41,0 -8,-3.59 -8,-8s3.59,-8 8,-8 8,3.59 8,8 -3.59,8 -8,8zM6.5,17.5l7.51,-3.49L17.5,6.5 9.99,9.99 6.5,17.5zM12,10.9c0.61,0 1.1,0.49 1.1,1.1s-0.49,1.1 -1.1,1.1 -1.1,-0.49 -1.1,-1.1 0.49,-1.1 1.1,-1.1z"/>
```